# cached php webpage content

Tags: php, caching

i have a webpage with a PHP switch on which I choose what page to display. A lot of the content is static and i wish to know how can i cache webpage for anonymous users.

can you help me with some ideas, links?

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at tutorial - [Caching Pages](http://php.dzone.com/news/php-caching-pages-with-output-)

Answer (score 0):

The Smarty templating engine has a cache built in: http://www.smarty.net/